# How to scale the cameras view bounds?

Tags: rendering, camera

The current issue is that I need more space to the right for my text, but scaling the camera to capture more of the area won't work. Why is this so?

This is what I wish to achieve: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSFmg.png]

But I am stuck with scaling the camera:[image]

(what is shown in red is what I wish to achieve)

How can I capture more of the area? (I prefer not to do any compositing).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also change the *Resolution* in <kbd>Render Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Dimensions</kbd>:

[image]

For this you probably want to increase the `X resolution`.

---

### Notice

Note that you can't scale the camera up by adjusting these values, you will need to move the camera and/or change the *Focal Length* to zoom/scale the camera.

- Adjust the *Focal Length* in *Properties > Camera > Lens*
- The easiest way to zoom in/out with the camera is:

  1. Enter *Camera view* (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>) and select the camera
  2. Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to move the camera along the local Z axis.

By using a combination of the above techniques, you can place and scale the camera however you want.

Answer (score 8):

In the example you give, you only want to increase the size on one side of the camera. You would have to.

- Increase the X resolution.
- Adjust the X shift to only cover the right side of the image (otherwise both sides will be increased evenly).

Answer (score 6):

If there is a reason why you can't move the camera to get the detail rendered you want you could change the Focal Length in the [Camera Properties](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Camera):

[image]

Another way is to change the [Aspect Ratio](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Output) note that changing these values will disort the image.

[image]

Comment: I'll see if there are any other answers. Thanks'

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is after changing camera mode to orthographic from perspective the camera stops scaling, adjust the orthographic scale

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In Blender 2.7 in "Display" settings.
Try Framing: Extend
[image: Try Framing: Extend]

Comment: how would this increase the camera render size? Can you elaborate a bit more on it, the answer is too vrief to clearly understand.